# How do I format a csv download from a url in Python?

Tags: python

I did this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from os.path import basename


# base url for csv links
base="https://www.nal.usda.gov/sites/www.nal.usda.gov/files/"
url = requests.get("https://www.nal.usda.gov/fnic/nutrient-lists-standard-reference-legacy-2018").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(url)
# check the urls for csv links
links_arr = []
for a in soup.select("a[href]"):
    if 'csv' in a:
        print(a["href"])
        link = a["href"]
        
        links_arr.append(link)
        req = requests.get(link)
        url_content = req.content
        
        csv_name = basename(link)
        file_path = "nutrient_name_csvs/" + csv_name
        with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
            f.writelines(str(url_content))
```

but the csv's end up like this:

```
b'"\nAbridged List Ordered by Nutrient Content in Household Measure\nSource: USDA National Nutrient Database for Standard Reference Legacy (2018)\nNutrients: Calcium, Ca(mg)\n",,\r\nDescription,Measure,"Calcium, Ca(mg)Per Measure"\r\n"Cheese, swiss","1.0 cups, diced",1175\r\n"Whey, sweet, dried",1.0 cups,1154\r\n"Cheese, pasteurized process, swiss","1.0 cups, diced",1081\r\n"Cheese, provolone","1.0 cups, diced",998\r\n"Cheese, muenster","1.0 cups, diced",946\r\n"Cheese, cheddar (Includes foods for USDA\'s Food Distribution Program)","1.0 cups, diced",937\r\n"Cheese, mozzarella, low moisture, part-skim","1.0 cups, diced",920\r\n"Tofu, raw, firm, prepared with calcium sulfate",0.5 cups,861\r\n"Cheese, mexican, queso chihuahua","1.0 cups, diced",859\r\n"Cheese, parmesan, grated",1.0 cups,853\r\n"Cheese spread, pasteurized process, American","1.0 cups, diced",787\r\n"Desserts, mousse, chocolate, prepared-from-recipe",1.0 recipe yield,776\r\n"Cheese food, pasteurized process, American, vitamin D fortified",1.0 cups,771\r\n"Cheese, feta","1.0 cups, crumbled",740\r\n"Cheese substitute, mozzarella","1.0 cups, shredded",689\r\n"Beverages, Whey protein powder isolate",3.0 scoop,600\r\n"Cheese, mozzarella, whole milk","1.0 cups, shredded",566\r\n"Cornmeal, white, self-rising, bolted, with wheat flour added, enriched",1.0 cups,508\r\n"Soybeans, green, raw",1.0 cups,504\r\n"Cornmeal, white, self-rising, degermed, enriched",1.0 cups,483\r\n"Beverages, UNILEVER, SLIMFAST, meal replacement, regular, ready-to-drink,  3-2-1 Plan",1.0 bottle,475\r\n"Milk, sheep, fluid",1.0 cups,473\r\n"Beverages, almond milk, chocolate, ready-to-drink",8.0 fl oz,451\r\n"Beverages, almond milk, sweetened, vanilla flavor, ready-to-drink",8.0 fl oz,451\r\n"Milk, dry, nonfat, regular, without added vitamin A and vitamin D",0.25 cups,377\r\n"Nuts, almonds, dry roasted, without salt added",1.0 cups whole kernels,370\r\n"Milk, buttermilk, dried",0.25 cups,355\r\n"Milk, nonfat, fluid, protein fortified, with added vitamin A and vitamin D (fat free and skim)",1.0 cups,352\r\n"Milk, reduced fat, fluid, 2% milkfat, protein fortified, with added vitamin A and vitamin D",1.0 cups,352\r\n"DIGIORNO Pizza, cheese topping, rising crust, frozen, baked",1.0 slice 1/4 of pie,351\r\n"Milk, lowfat, fluid, 1% milkfat, protein fortified, with added vitamin A and vitamin D",1.0 cups,349\r\n"Orange juice, chilled, includes from concentrate, with added calcium",1.0 cups,349\r\n"Orange juice, chilled, includes from concentrate, with added calcium and vitamin D",1.0 cups,349\r\n"Cheese, ricotta, part skim milk",0.5 cups,337\r\nEggnog,1.0 cups,330\r\n"Wheat flour, white, all-purpose, enriched, calcium-fortified",1.0 cups,315\r\n"Yogurt, plain, low fat",1.0 container (6 oz),311\r\n"Cheese, pasteurized process, American, fortified with vitamin D",1.0 oz,296\r\n"Milk, producer, fluid, 3.7% milkfat",1.0 cups,290\r\n"Yogurt, fruit, low fat, 11g protein/8 oz",1.0 container (6 oz),287\r\n"Milk, chocolate, fluid, commercial, whole, with added vitamin A and vitamin D",1.0 cups,280\r\n"Amaranth leaves, cooked, boiled, drained, without salt",1.0 cups,276\r\n"Beans, pink, mature seeds, raw",1.0 cups,273\r\n"Milk, chocolate, fluid, commercial, reduced fat, with added vitamin A and vitamin D",1.0 cups,272\r\n"Soybeans, green, cooked, boiled, drained, without salt",1.0 cups,261\r\n"Cheese, ricotta, whole milk",0.5 cups,255\r\n"Turnip greens, frozen, cooked, boiled, drained, without salt",1.0 cups,249\r\n"Garlic, raw",1.0 cups,246\r\n"Fast foods, english muffin, with egg, cheese, and canadian bacon",1.0 sandwich,242\r\n"Fish, salmon, pink, canned, drained solids",3.0 oz,241\r\n"Beans, black, mature seeds, raw",1.0 cups,239\r\n"Yogurt, fruit, low fat,9 g prote
```

How do I write all the csv's so they look like csv's?  I mean,without characters for newline and I think /r is carriage return as well as others?
The links look like:

```
https://www.nal.usda.gov/sites/www.nal.usda.gov/files/carbohydrate.csv
https://www.nal.usda.gov/sites/www.nal.usda.gov/files/polyunsat_fat.csv
https://www.nal.usda.gov/sites/www.nal.usda.gov/files/protein.csv
https://www.nal.usda.gov/sites/www.nal.usda.gov/files/sat_fat.csv
https://www.nal.usda.gov/sites/www.nal.usda.gov/files/total_dietary_fiber.csv
https://www.nal.usda.gov/sites/www.nal.usda.gov/files/total_sugar.csv
https://www.nal.usda.gov/sites/www.nal.usda.gov/files/Total_Kcal.csv
https://www.nal.usda.gov/sites/www.nal.usda.gov/files/calcium.csv
```

Note: the above code was heavily borrowed from other answers on this site.

Comment: `req = requests.get(link)` gives you a `Response`, and then `req.content` is the raw bytes of the response data. You instead want the text that it represents, which is `req.text`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, thanks, I'll try that, I was going to try this next, `decoded_content = url_content.decode('utf-8')` but now that I know it's response data your way sounds correct.

Comment: That way should also work, assuming the encoding is correct. I think Requests can try to detect the encoding automatically, so using its built-in functionality is better. (BTW: It can also parse a JSON request for you automatically, by accessing the `.json` instead.)

Comment: @Karl That's really awesome.